# Erase duplicate files?

Tags: backup, duplicate-files, duplicate

I have a 1 TB hard drive which I have been using for backups for a few years. The problem is I only did backups by hand. So now I have a lot of duplicates saved up.
Is there a software or a script that will scan the drive for duplicate files, let me choose what to keep and what to delete?
Bonus points if it shows me the time and date of last modification to the file.

Comment: Not an exact dupe, nevertheless the answers work here as well: http://askubuntu.com/questions/547437/find-delete-duplicated-files-on-multiple-harddisks-at-once/547791#547791

Answer (score 2):

There is a good software with a GUI to do that called `Fslint` that you can install by your  default repositories:

```
apt-get update && apt-get install fslint
```

With this  software, you can detect duplicates files by using the names but  also the content (may be longer with content).